# Proper input/output for python code in a pig udf?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

I have this short python script:

```
import langid
import sys

for pig_tuple in sys.stdin:
    cols = pig_tuple.split()

    if len(cols) < 2:
        sys.exit(0)

    try:
        id = int(cols[0])
        text = " ".join(cols[1:])
    except:
        sys.exit(0)

    (lang,prob) = langid.classify(text)
    print "%s\t%s" %(id,lang)

sys.exit(0)
```

I would like to run it inside a pig script. I tried:

```
define langid_cmd `python2.6 /data/test/compiled_python/langid_command_line.py` ship('/data/test/compiled_python/langid_command_line.py');

text = LOAD '$PIG_INPUT' USING PigStorage() as (text:chararray);

pythonDetect1 = STREAM text through langid_cmd AS (pid:chararray,planguage:chararray);
```

but I get:

```
2013-03-29 15:53:22,290 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2013-03-29 15:53:22,303 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
Details at logfile: /home/isl/ryan/src/main/pigScripts/pig_1364597410350.log
2013-03-29 15:53:22,306 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
Details at logfile: /home/isl/ryan/src/main/pigScripts//src/main/pigScripts/pig_1364597410350.log
2013-03-29 15:53:22,308 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
Details at logfile: /home/isl/ryan/src/main/pigScripts//src/main/pigScripts/pig_1364597410350.log
2013-03-29 15:53:22,311 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
Details at logfile: /home/isl/ryan/src/main/pigScripts/src/main/pigScripts/pig_1364597410350.log
2013-03-29 15:53:22,313 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
Details at logfile: /home/isl/ryan/src/main/pigScripts/src/main/pigScripts/pig_1364597410350.log
```

The directory /data/test/compiled_python is chmod'd to 777, and when I run this from the shell:

```
-bash-3.2$ echo 14353 I can haz pigscriptz? | python /data/test/compiled_python/langid_command_line.py 
14353   eu
```

??

Answer (score 0):

The `AS (pid:chararray,planguage:chararray)` tells pig to expect an output that is a tuple of strings but you return  tab delimited strings. You should return print out the results as

```
print "(%s,%s)" %(id,lang)
```

[or use the python UDF integration](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html#python-udfs)